# Uk visa bank statements

Tags: visas, uk, proof-provenance-of-funds

I just want to ask, since i started working i never asked for debit card because i was thinking of just opening bank account for my "savings" because i am saving money to travel to UK this year but i just saw one of the discussions about bank statements that the final balance doesn't matter but what matters is the cash flow on the account but on my case the account i opened is a checking account.. Would that be a problem when i apply for uk visa? Please help i am worried :'(

Answer (score 0):

You will likely have a problem if your bank statements show only cash credits that don’t tie up with their source eg salary. See [Should I submit bank statements when applying for a UK Visa? What do they say about me?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab) for more explicit information